# assembly visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, assembly

```
; 5    :    int c=0;

    mov DWORD PTR _c$[ebp], 0
```

I don't understand the syntax, why c is referenced without bracket and why add [ebp] ?

Comment: thxs for the unreal down vote....must be a clever guy i guess

Comment: +1 because who downvotes a question..

Comment: There is something called `Assembly Language`. Though they don't show it to kids anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EBP` is the frame pointer. Since c is a local variable or argument, `c` is an offset relative to the frame pointer.